# hover function not working as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, jquery-hover

Here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ganganp/x62wR/5/

```
     $('#rotator0 div').hover(
     function () {
            ssrc = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
            valt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt");
            (this).children('img').attr('src','http://placehold.it/150x150&text='+valt);
     }, 
     function () {
           $(this).children('img').attr('src',ssrc);
     }
 );
```

hover for the inner circle images not working.
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Inner circle lays below outter one, so your cursor always hover outter rotater, you can put `console.log()` into each function and will see when it fired

Comment: `<div id="rotator">` is sitting on top of `<div id="rotator0">` and preventing the hover action from reaching the inner items. http://jsfiddle.net/x62wR/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments #rotator0 is below #rotator and this breaks hover events

Adding css property:

```
#rotator0 {
    z-index:10;
}
```

seems to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/x62wR/18/

However now hovering on outer circle works buggy as the corners of the smaller #rotator0 now overrides the bigger one. You will have to change its width height to something small enough and relocate it.